# Slow read from HttpRequest.InputStream over HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, https

I have an MVC controller, which I would like to accept a payload in HTTP body.
Files that are sent can be pretty large, so I want to use Stream.

Over HTTP it works well, but over HTTPS it takes ages to read the stream.
Even something stupid like code below takes ~35 seconds for 16MB payload.

```
var s = HttpRequest.InputStream
```

I tried `HttpRequest.InputStream` as well as `HttpRequest.GetBufferlessStream()` but final effect is the same.

Here are my CPU usage charts. The part where usage is high is taking place after the read, and there my further processing is done. But this low CPU usage part is what bothers me.

[image: HTTP request] [image: HTTPS request]

#### Update 1:

What Kevin wrote makes sense.
Here is another chart, comparing CPU usage for Postman from which perform request and my app on IIS. There is clearly a point where transmission over HTTPS stops and actual work starts.

[image: Postman vs IIS]

Comment: HTTPS encrypts outgoing data and decrypts incoming data, this is not free there is overhead.